# datepicker update value in two differents UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uibutton, uitextfield

I'm trying to update two buttons with datepicker. Button startDate et endDate. I don't how can I update these butttons with differents datepicker.

Maybe with handler ?

**user story : the user click on startDat datepicker is displaying, user choose any date or time, then click on endDate and same action.**

**EDIT:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextLabel: UILabel!
    var whoTriggeredPickerView: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var startDateTextButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var endDateTextButton : UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var datePick : UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func donePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        dateTextLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        startDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()
        endDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()     
    }

    func donePressedButton(_ sender :UIButton){
        startDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()
        endDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func tappedToolBarBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

        startDateTextButton.setTitle(dateformatter.string(from: Date()), for: .normal)
        endDateTextButton.setTitle(dateformatter.string(from: Date()), for: .normal)

        startDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()
        endDateTextButton.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func closeDatePicker(){
         self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        closeDatePicker()
    }

    @IBAction func BtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        let datePickerView: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

         //sender.inputView = datePickerView
        self.view.addSubview(datePickerView)
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        self.whoTriggeredPickerView = sender
    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium

        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
        //dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

        if self.whoTriggeredPickerView == startDateTextButton {
            // set startDateBtn title
             startDateTextButton.setTitle(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()), for: .normal)
        }else if self.whoTriggeredPickerView == endDateTextButton {
            // set endDateBtn title
            endDateTextButton.setTitle(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()), for: .normal)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:
You can create a tmp variable to record picker is triggered by which button. Then you can decide which button's title you want to set.

```
//In your view controller:
var whoTriggeredPickerView: UIButton?

//In your BtnClicked function:
self.whoTriggeredPickerView = sender

//Then in datePickerValueChanged function:
if self.whoTriggeredPickerView == StartDateButton {
   // set startDateBtn title
}else if self.whoTriggerPickerView == endDateButton {
   // set endDateBtn title
}
```

Some suggestions:

1. always lowercase the instance name, you are using `DatePick` as the instance name of `UIDatePicker`, instead, you should name it as `datePicker`; for function names as well.
2. for your case you can use two textfields instead of buttons.

   `let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
   datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
   startDateTextField.inputView = datePicler
   endDateTextField.inputView = datePicker`

Comment: 2nd suggestion doesn't work, datepicker update all the field,I want update field by current datepicker. How can I do this with tmp variable ?

Comment: @kakame91 answer updated, please notice you have to change your `BtnClicked ` 's parameter Class type to UIButton instead of AnyObject; Still, I recommend you to use textfield instead of UIButton.

Comment: doesn't work I can't leave the current datepicker, and date is blocked on default date  :( (see above the Edited post)

Comment: @kakame91 Hi, I create this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jhonny-me/8cffed8f37b727496d659d0e06ad3d4a) for you, check it out.

Comment: how can I generate days array with datepicker range ??